# Using NSFileWrapper in NSDocument made of various files

Tags: cocoa, nsdocument, nsfilewrapper

I'm making a document-based Cocoa app in which the document is dynamic a collection of files (users can add or remove files). In particular, **the Save and Open operations should be as fast as possible**.

If I understand the documentation correctly, I should use [`NSFileWrapper`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFileWrapper_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and implement [`fileWrapperOfType:error`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDocument/fileWrapperOfType:error:) and [`readFromFileWrapper:ofType:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDocument/readFromFileWrapper:ofType:error:). However, I can't find a complete code example. How should I implement the following methods?

```
#pragma mark - NSDocument

- (NSFileWrapper *)fileWrapperOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
    return nil;
}

- (BOOL)readFromFileWrapper:(NSFileWrapper *)fileWrapper ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - My methods

- (void) addFileToDocumentFromURL:(NSURL*)fileURL {
    // Add a file to the document given the file URL
}

- (void) removeFileFromDocumentWithName:(NSString*)name {
    // Remove a file from the document given the file name
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Putting together [bits](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/DocumentPackages/DocumentPackages.html) and [pieces](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/AdvancedTopics/AdvancedTopics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011179-CH7-SW10) from the documentation:

```
- (NSFileWrapper*) fileWrapperOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)outError {
    return self.documentFileWrapper;
}

- (BOOL) readFromFileWrapper:(NSFileWrapper *)fileWrapper ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)outError {
    self.documentFileWrapper = fileWrapper;
    return YES;
}

- (void) addFileToDocumentFromURL:(NSURL*)fileURL {
    NSData* fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
    NSFileWrapper *fileWrapper = [[NSFileWrapper alloc] initRegularFileWithContents:fileData];
    fileWrapper.preferredFilename = [fileURL lastPathComponent];
    [self.documentFileWrapper addFileWrapper:fileWrapper];
    [self updateChangeCount:NSChangeDone];
}

- (void) removeFileFromDocumentWithName:(NSString*)name {
    NSFileWrapper *fileWrapper = [self.documentFileWrapper.fileWrappers objectForKey:name];
    if (fileWrapper) {
        [self.documentFileWrapper removeFileWrapper:fileWrapper];
        [self updateChangeCount:NSChangeDone];
    }
}

- (NSFileWrapper*) documentFileWrapper {
    if (!_documentFileWrapper) { // New document
        _documentFileWrapper = [[NSFileWrapper alloc] initDirectoryWithFileWrappers:nil];
    }
    return _documentFileWrapper;
}
```